# Can the + wildcard match 0 levels?

Tags: mqtt

I'm confused on one bit of the MQTT specification regarding the `+` wildcard. Can `+` be used to match 0 levels?

For example, consider a subscriber on `+/b/c`. I believe it should get messages sent to `a/b/c`, `x/b/c`, `y/b/c`, and even `/b/c`. However, should it also get messages sent to `b/c` (i.e. no leading `/`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `+` will only match a whole level of topic hierarchy, it will not (and should not) match `b/c` in the example given.

From the 5.0 spec:

> 4.7.1.3 Single-level wildcard
>
> The plus sign (‘+’ U+002B) is a wildcard character that matches *only
> one topic level*.

The relevant part being the "matches only one topic level", not "matches zero or one topic level"

p.s. please don't use leading `/` on topics while technically legal in the spec, it inserts a `null` (e.g. `<null>/b/c` hence how it matches the pattern in the question) in the topic hierarchy, which is a pain to parse and  breaks things like shared subscriptions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how a leading `/` breaks shared subscriptions? Also, aren't the specifics regarding pattern matching and parsing implementation dependent?

Comment: Shared subscriptions work by adding a prefix to the topic e.g.`$shared/foobar/a/b/c` subscribes to the topic `a/b/c` as part of group `foobar`, but `$shared/foobar//a/b/c` is not going to validate as a good topic (It's also bloody confusing). And no, topic wildcard matching are part of the spec https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901242

Comment: I understand the specification defines how parsing should *behave*, but it doesn't dictate how the parsing is implemented (e.g. using `<null>` with a leading `/`), right?

Comment: Here `null` means empty, in pretty much any implementation language empty maps to `null` (if we really want to niggle, in JS it could be `undefined`), but for the general case it's `null`. But that doesn't change the fact that the answer to your original question is "No it will not match `b/c`"

Comment: I like your answer, and I'm inclined to mark it as correct. However, the stuff in the "p.s." is tripping me up. I just don't see where the MQTT spec is dictating implementation details as you suggest. Also, a leading `/` doesn't appear to break shared subscriptions on at least one of the MQTT brokers I've tried.